# Redirecionamento com parametros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
public ActionResult exemplo()
```

Que retorna:

```
int act = (int)TasksTypeEnum.CARGA;
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { q = study.Id, msg = 1, action = act });
```

O index da pagina recebe:

```
public ActionResult Index(int q, int msg = 0, int action = 0)
```

porem o ultimo parametro action vem zerado ! e a url acaba ficando assim:

```
Ciclos?q=3886&msg=1
```

o valor disto: int act = `(int)TasksTypeEnum.CARGA;` é = 1

```
public enum TasksTypeEnum
    {
        CARGA = 1,
        STATUS = 2,
        SINISTRO = 3, 
        EMAIL = 4,
        CONTATOTELEFONICO = 5      
    }
```

Por que esta ignorando este ultimo parâmetro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parâmetro action que você está usando já é reservado para o nome da action a ser chamada, pois assim foi definido no cadastro da rota:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        action=RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

O ideal seria você alterar o nome do parâmetro como no exemplo abaixo:

```
int act = (int)TasksTypeEnum.CARGA;
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { q = study.Id, msg = 1, _action = act });
```

---

```
public ActionResult Index(int q, int msg = 0, int _action = 0)
```

Caso não seja possível, tente usar um arroba antes do nome do parâmetro (não testei):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { q = study.Id, msg = 1, @action = act  });
```

Comment: Cara nem me toquei disso, vlw mesmo